# Difficult Limit Problem without L'hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> $$\lim_\limits{x\to-1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{26-x}-\sqrt{8-x}}{3x^2+4x+1}$$

I was asked to solve this problem without using l'hopital's rule. Using Mathematica it shows that we should rationalize first but the algebra gets quite nasty near the end so I was wondering if there was a better way of approaching this problem...

Comment: How did you rationalize? Notice that if you do it correctly, you can simply skip a lot of manipulations when you just put in $x=-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {(26-x)^\frac 13 - (8-x)^\frac 12}{(3x + 1)(x+1)}$

We are going to multiply top and bottom by a factor that will clear out the fractional roots.

Note that:

$a^6 - b^6 = (a-b)(a^5+a^4b + a^3b^2 + a^2b^3 + ab^4 + b^5)$

Let $a = (26-x)^\frac 13$  Let $b = (8-x)^\frac 12$

$\frac {(a-b)(a^5+a^4b + a^3b^2 + a^2b^3 + ab^4 + b^5)}{(3x+1)(x+1)(a^5+a^4b + a^3b^2 + a^2b^3 + ab^4 + b^5)}\\
\frac {a^6-b^6}{(3x+1)(x+1)(a^5+a^4b + a^3b^2 + a^2b^3 + ab^4 + b^5)}\\
\frac {(26-x)^2 - (8-x)^3}{(3x+1)(x+1)(a^5+a^4b + a^3b^2 + a^2b^3 + ab^4 + b^5)}$

Lets multiply out and simplify the numerator.  We will ignore the denominator for now.

$(26-x)^2 - (8-x)^3\\
676 - 52x + x^2 - (512 - 192x + 24x^2 - x^3)\\
x^3 - 23x^2 +140x + 164$

We knew from the beginning that the numerator equaled zero when $x - 1$  Multiplying by our factor to rationalize the numerator doesn't change that.  $(x+1)$ is a factor of the numerator.

$x^3 - 23x^2 +140x + 164 = (x+1)(x^2 - 24x + 164)$

$\lim_\limits{x\to-1}\frac {(x+1)(x^2 - 24x + 164)}{(3x+1)(x+1)(a^5+a^4b + a^3b^2 + a^2b^3 + ab^4 + b^5)}$

We can cancel the $x+1$ factor, and evaluate the rest at $x = -1.$  When $x = 1$ both  $a$ and $b$ equal $3.$

$\frac {189}{(-2)(3^5)(6)} = -\frac {7}{108}$

Answer (score 0):

Here is just a short sketch of a not so cumbersome algebraic solution.

Looking at $26=3^3-1$ and $8=3^2-1$, intuition may guide you to set $x=y-1$ and consider

$$\lim_\limits{x\to-1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{26-x}-\sqrt{8-x}}{3x^2+4x+1} = \lim_\limits{y\to \color{blue}{0}}\underbrace{\frac{\sqrt[3]{27-y}-\sqrt{9-y}}{3(y-1)^2+4(y-1)+1}}_{=\frac{\sqrt[3]{27-y}-\sqrt{9-y}}{(3y-2)y}}$$

This looks much nicer and, since $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac 1{3y-2}=-\frac 12$, we only need to consider

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{27-y}-\sqrt{9-y}}{y}= \underbrace{\frac{\sqrt[3]{27-y}-3}{y}}_{= -\frac 1{\sqrt[3]{(27-y)^2} + \sqrt[3]{(27-y)\cdot 27} +\sqrt[3]{27^2}}} - \frac{\sqrt{9-y}-3}{y}$$

The last term you may handle with the standard binomial formula.

So, putting all together you will get (not forgetting $\frac 1{3y-2}$)

$$-\frac 12\left(-\frac 1{27} + \frac 16\right) = -\frac 7{108}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt[m]{1+x}-1}{x}=\frac{1}{m}$$
we can write
$$\lim_\limits{x\to-1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{26-x}-\sqrt{8-x}}{3x^2+4x+1}=\lim_\limits{x\to-1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{27-(x+1)}-\sqrt{9-(x+1)}}{(x+1)(3x+1)}=\\
=3\lim_\limits{x\to-1}\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{x+1}{-27}}-1\right)-\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{x+1}{-9}}-1 \right)}{(x+1)(3x+1)}=\\
=3\lim_\limits{x\to-1}\frac{\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{x+1}{-27}}-1\right)}{\frac{x+1}{-27}}\cdot\frac{x+1}{-27}-
\frac{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{x+1}{-9}}-1 \right)}{\frac{x+1}{-9} }\cdot\frac{x+1}{-9}}{(x+1)(3x+1)}=
3\frac{\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{-27}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{-9}}{-2}=\\
=-\frac 12\left(-\frac 1{27} + \frac 16\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=(1+z)^{2/3}+(1+z)^{1/3}+1.$ We have $[(1+z)^{1/3}-1]f(z)=z.$ So $(1+z)^{1/3}=1+z/f(z).$ We have $1/f(z)\to 1/3$ as $z\to 0$ so let $1/f(z)=(1 +g(z))/3 $ where $g(z)\to 0$ as $z\to 0.$ Then $$(1+z)^{1/3}=1+(z/3)(1+g(z)).$$

For $|z|<1$ let $h(z)=(1+z)^{1/2}+1.$ We have $[(1+z)^{1/2}-1]h(z)=z.$ So $(1+z)^{1/2}=1+z/h(z).$ We have $1/h(z)\to 1/2$ as $z\to 0$ so let $1/h(z)=(1+j(z))/2 $ where $j(z)\to 0$ as $z\to 0.$ Then $$(1+z)^{1/2}=1+(z/2)(1+j(z)).$$

Let $x=-1+y.$

For $|y|$ small enough that $(1+y/9)^{1/2}\in \Bbb R$ we have $$(26-x)^{1/3}-(8-x)^{1/2}=(27+y)^{1/3}-(9+y)^{1/2}=$$ $$=3 (1+y/27)^{1/3}-3(1+y/9)^{1/2}=$$ $$=3[1+(y/81)(1+g(y/27))]-3[1+(y/18)(1+j(y/9))]=$$ $$= 3(1+y/81)-3(1+y/18)+yk(y)=$$ $$=y(-7/54+k(y))$$ where $k(y)\to 0$ as $y\to 0,$ i.e. as $x\to -1.$

FYI. $k(y)=g(y/27)/27-j(y/9)/6.$

The denominator in the Q is $3x^2+4x+1=(x+1)(3x+1)=y(3y-2).$ So the whole expression is $\frac {y(-7/54+k(y))}{y(3y-2)}=\frac {-7/54+k(y)}{3y-2}$ with $y\to 0$ and $k(y)\to 0.$

Comment: In general, for $|z|<1$ we have $(1+z)^r=1+(rz)(1+F_r(z))$ where $F_r(z)\to 0$ as $z\to 0$.